# Can the command-line window be entered without interrupting macro recording?

Tags: command-line, macro, command-line-window

I'm having a problem using the command-line window (`help cmdwin`),
which is extremely useful, but it doesn't play well with macros.

cmdwin is invoked with `q:`, so if there is a macro being recorded, the 'q' ends the recording.

Here's the general chain of events:

```
qw          # start recording a macro in register w
q:          # enter cmdwin to perform a command,
            # expecting it to be recorded, but the q cancels the
            # macro
```

I don't think it's relevant, but I have `:` mapped to `q:`, making
cmdwin the default way of invoking commands.  I *love* cmdwin, but
macros are essential.

Is there a way to make them play nicely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the command line window with the alternate command `:<C-F>`, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> when in command line mode. Eventually you can rebind `:` to `:<C-F>`.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.  I updated my mappings and it works flawlessly. `:<C-F>` for commands, `/<C-F>` and `?<C-F>` for search.